# R submitting archived package to CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran, package-development

One of my R package [DiallelAnalysisR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiallelAnalysisR/index.html) was removed from the CRAN  repository. Now I fixed the problem and want to resubmit it to CRAN. However, after submitted the package I got the following NOTE

```
CRAN teams' auto-check service
Flavor: r-devel-windows-ix86+x86_64
Check: CRAN incoming feasibility, Result: NOTE
  Maintainer: 'Muhammad Yaseen <myaseen208@gmail.com>'
```

Any hints to fix this NOTE. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to fix. AFAIK, the CRAN checks always produce a note showing the maintainer.

Comment: You actually don't need to do anything. Just mention in `cran_comments` why the package got archived and that you have fixed the cause of that, and that's it. You can ignore this `NOTE`.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil: Thanks for your useful comment. Would appreciate if your change your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to do anything. Just mention in `cran_comments.md` why the package got archived and that you have fixed the cause of that, and that's it.

You can ignore this `NOTE`.